# Testcafe Runner inside a Promise

Tags: javascript, promise, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am new to Promise so need to know how to put this testcafe runner inside a Promise function so that I can use it later to call Promise.race

```
  const createTestCafe = require('testcafe');
    let testcafe         = null;

    createTestCafe('localhost', 1337, 1338)
        .then((tc) => {
            testcafe       = tc;
            const runner   = testcafe.createRunner();


            return runner
                .src(['test.ts'])
                .browsers(['chrome'])
                 .run({skipJsErrors:true});


    })

    .catch(failedCount => {
        console.log('Tests failed: ' + failedCount);
        testcafe.close();
    })
    .then(successCount => {
            console.log('Tests success: ' + successCount);
            testcafe.close();
    });
```

I need that testcafe runner runs as Promise function how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The [run](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/programming-interface/runner.html#run) method of TestCafe's Runner class returns a promise, so you can store it in a variable in the same manner as you did with the TestCafe instance:

```
const createTestCafe = require('testcafe');
let testcafe = null;

const testRunPromise = createTestCafe('localhost', 1337, 1338)
    .then(tc => {
        testcafe = tc;
        const runner = testcafe.createRunner();


        return runner
            .src(['test.ts'])
            .browsers(['chrome'])
            .run({ skipJsErrors: true });
    });

testRunPromise
    .catch(failedCount => {
        console.log('Tests failed: ' + failedCount);
        testcafe.close();
    })
    .then(successCount => {
        console.log('Tests success: ' + successCount);
        testcafe.close();
    });

Promise.race([testRunPromise/*, yourAnotherPromise*/]);
```